# How to check elasticsearch snapshot status every X seconds using while loop in python?

Tags: python, bash, elasticsearch, snapshot

I'm trying to configure a status check **python** code of running snapshot, that will catch that will continue when the status is "IN_PROGRESS" or "STARTED" and will exit and do something for each other status. 
for example, in BASH it'll be something like:

```
while [ "$SNAP_STATUS" == "IN_PROGRESS" ] || [ "$SNAP_STATUS" == "STARTED" ] && [ "$counter" -lt 150 ]
do
    sleep 60
    SNAP_STATUS=$(curl -s -X GET "$ELASTIC_SERVER:9200/_snapshot/$REPOSITORY/$SNAPSHOT/_status"?pretty | jq .snapshots[].state -r)
    echo "SNAPSHOT NAME: $SNAPSHOT - STATUS: $SNAP_STATUS"
    counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
    echo $counter
done

if [[ "$SNAP_STATUS" == "SUCCESS" ]] ; then
    echo "YAY!"
else
    echo "BOO..."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly:

```
import requests
from time import sleep

your_snapshot_url = ""
snap_status = "IN_PROGRESS"
counter = 0
while snap_status == "IN_PROGRESS" or (snap_status == "STARTED" and counter < 150):
    sleep(60)
    req = requests.get(your_snapshot_url).content
    snap_status = req['snapshots']['state'] # Replace with whatever you need to parse the state
    counter += 1
    print(counter)

if snap_status == "SUCCESS":
    print("YAY!")
else:
    print("BOO...")
```

This will make a request to **your_snapshot_url** every 60 sec while incrementing the counter every cycle.
The while loop will exit when **the snap_status** if anything other then IN_PROGRESS, or is STARTED but the counter is less then 150

Upon exiting, you receive a "YAY" print if snap status is SUCCESS or 'BOO" otherwise

Comment: Thank you @alin-iuga , but I meant using elasticsearch package